# FileSystemWatcher would not display frame in a short time

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I use a pictureBox to display the jpg file. I create the new picture in the folder, I use the FileSystemWatcher to watch the folder, when Created Event be raised, I get the image stream to display.

But when the Created event be raised, I update the pictureBox.Image property to the new Stream, but it's not display in the pictureBox. // Use the test console program in the project PicturesVideoGenerator

When I copy a new jpg file, and paste it into the folder, it can display.

What's wrong with me?

Check the code here : https://github.com/volnet/PicturesVideoPlayer/issues/1

Comment: `What's wrong with me?`  Is that *really* your question

Answer (score 1):

When the File is created, it may not have contents yet in it and could be `0Kb` file. Remember, `Created` event is raised when the file is created and not when the file has some data.

You need to hook `Changed` event. Keep a check when was last `Changed` event fired and if there is a substantial gap between last changed, assume the file has been completely written.

Example of your case:

```
Action                     | Event
1. Create a new file       | Created Event
2. Added some content      | Changed Event
3. Added some more content | Changed event
```

so when 2 and 3 have a gap say 5 seconds, you assume that the user have completed writing the file to disk.

```
DateTime dtLastWrite = DateTime.Now;
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   dtLastWrite = DateTime.Now();
}
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtLastWrite).TotalSeconds > 5)
      ReadTheFileNow(); //start to read the file now.
   else
      dtLastWrite = DateTime.Now;
}
```